# How to replace the Nth occurrence of a word in a string?

Tags: python

For a given string how can one replace the Nth occurrence of a word (substring) for a different word using Python3

### Example

For the string 'here i have the word here 3 times have here' replace the second appearance of the word 'here' with the word 'have' creating a new string 'here i have the word have 3 times have here'

```
string = 'here i have the word here 3 times have here'
old_word = 'here'
new_word = 'have'
position = 2 #second appearance
new_string = replacement_function(string, old_word, new_word, position)
print(new_string )
```

Output:

```
'here i have the word have 3 times have here'
```

Comment: What is the exact rule that tells you what part of the string you want to replace? For example, will it always be the second occurrence of the test string? Or does it just depend on the position within the original string, or exactly what??? And what will the replacement be?

Comment: Thank you for your nice doubt. I will edit my description.

Comment: What did you not understand from the hits you got on "Python string replace"?  Show your code and the specific problem.

Comment: I want to check if a string ends with a sub-string. If it ends with the sub-string, then I want to replace only the ending occurrance with the replacement string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 'I have a banana and a banana and another banana'
word = 'banana'
replace_with = 'apple'
occurrance  = 2
word.join(s.split(word)[:occurrance]) + replace_with + word.join(s.split(word)[occurrance:])
```

```
'I have a banana and a apple and another banana'
```

If you just want to process the last occurance
then make `occurrance  = -1`